# vim YouCompleteMe path to compilation_database_folder

Tags: vim, cmake

so there's a minor but non the less annoying problem I encountered when loading the compilation_database that has been generated from cmake in the .ycm_extra_conf.py

```
# Path to the compile_commands.json that is generated by cmake
# (some how this doesn't work, if path is not explicit?)
compilation_database_folder = '/home/user/programming/someproject/build'
```

Passing here an explicit path works no problem at all, although I kind of want to specify a relative path to the root directory of my project. After 2h of searching and trial and error I want some answers now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you know where your *.ycm_extra_conf.py* file is located. So you can get a Path "relative" to this file like this:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/build"
```

This will get the directory of your ycm config file and adds the build directory to it. If your directory is located above this one just use *os.path.dirname* again.

Comment: Yeah that's it... I guess I should start learning some python.